# Removing notificationbar for kiosk mode

Tags: android, kiosk

I am trying to build an android app in kiosk-mode in Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean). What I have achieved till now is to make the application as full screen and also handled the home and back buttons. However, my problem is, I want to remove the status/notification bar. I don't want the user to access any other settings through it. I have tried out many ways including the usage of different flags available in android `WindowManager` for having a screen devoid of the notification bar. However, none were helpful for that.

I have read about apps like Surelock which serve this purpose. Therefore, at least I know that there is something which can be done, except rooting, to remove the notification bar.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Sadly, what you want will require rooting the device: http://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/  Even when you suppress the title bar a swipe down will make it reappear.

Comment: yes thats exactly what is happening. Even after using all the solutions that I found after googling, the status bar just hides temporarily. But as soon as I swipe again it reappears. :(

Comment: Sorry, firmware feature.  Android doesn't natively offer a 'secure single app kiosk' mode.

Comment: Is there any workaround for the same ?

Comment: The workaround is the thing I linked.  Root the device and override the swipe behavior.